# Div position in the middle of another vertical div

Tags: html, css, less

I would like to add flight duration in the middle-left of each blue line. I was trying to do following tricks, but unfortunately doesn't work.

This is how to looks like at the moment:

[image]

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyXvgB?editors=110)

HTML:

```
<span class="col-md-12 roundtrip">
  <div class="col-md-6 trip">Outbound
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="connection">5hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="connection">2hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 trip">Inbound
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
  </div>
</span>
```

LESS:

```
.roundtrip {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.trip {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 50%;
}

.flight {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.flight-path {
  width: 6px;
  min-height: 85px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #6090FF;
}

.connection {
  height: 40px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flight-duration{
    margin:auto auto auto 0;
}
```

Comment: If the problem is how to do it fundamentally, and not how to convert working CSS into Less, then you should just post the CSS, and not tag your question with the Less tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of my favorite tricks:

```
.element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Applied to your specific example:

```css
.roundtrip {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.trip {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 3px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 50%;
}
.flight {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.flight-path {
  width: 6px;
  min-height: 85px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #6090FF;
  position: relative;
}
.connection {
  height: 40px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flight-duration {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
  /* Just messing around, centering the text horizontally too */
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  width: 81px;
  left: -38px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="col-md-12 roundtrip">
  <div class="col-md-6 trip">Outbound
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="connection">5hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">Chicago</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="connection">2hr wait</div>
    <div class="flight">New York</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 trip">Inbound
    <div class="flight">Amsterdam</div>
    <div class="flight-path">
      <div class="flight-duration">1-30h</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flight">Los Angeles</div>
  </div>
</span>
```

[Source](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuimg it's the '1-30h' text you're wanting to move:

Try positioning your .flight-duration class with this:

```
    .flight-duration {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin:20px 0px 0px -40px;
}
```

The -40px is affecting the left-hand margin, the lower the number the further left your text will sit. Higher numbers will cause the text to sit on the right of the blue line.

Comment: Thanks Chris, unfortunately didn't work. Do you think you can try it on CodePen I have just created? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyXvgB?editors=110

Comment: length of the `flight-path` depends on number of changes, so applying settings you have provided works fine some cases but doesn't work if path is longer then expected. Idea here is to set element in the middle dynamically.

Comment: Try with the absolute positioning and the -50% Y translation in the edit I just made, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, add this to your code :)

```
.flight-path {
  position: relative;
}
.flight-duration{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    width: 46px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

I forked your codepen, to show a new demo
http://codepen.io/antraxis/pen/jbPpQY?editors=110